# What is my app's availability on the iOS App Store?

Tags: app-store

I just changed my app to `Ready for Sale`. Does that mean it's immediately available in all geographic areas? If not, is there a way to track the rollout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual rule of thumb mentioned a couple of times in the official docs is that it can take up to 24 hours for your app to become available/visible in all territories. From my own experience with our 50 apps and many updates there is no clear "rollout" and also no definitive way to track it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html